# `extern` array default value as `weak` symbol

Tags: c++, arduino, avr

I'm making a keyboard firmware, where I'd like to declare a "configuration" array (with a default value that would make to main code do "nothing") that a user could override (thus turning on the feature). Is it possible without ODR violation? I'm getting "array types have different bounds" (as the default array has 1 element and my "user" array has more)

combo.h

```cpp
class Combo {
   ...
};

extern Combo combos[];
extern const uint8_t combos_count;

#define COMBOS(...) __VA_ARGS__; const uint8_t combos_count = sizeof(combos)/sizeof(combos[0]);
```

combo.cpp

```
__attribute__((weak)) Combo combos[] = { dummy_combo_value_because_empty_array_not_supported };
__attribute__((weak)) extern const uint8_t combos_count = 0;
```

I'd like to do the following:

user_keymap.cpp

```cpp
#include "combo.h"

Combo combos[] = COMBOS({
    combo1,
    combo2,
    combo3
});
```

The whole reason I'm trying to do it like this is because I cannot easily `#ifdef` away this whole functionality when not used. Ideally my code would be optimized away with `if (combos_count > 0)`. The `COMBOS` macro is in this form, because I need the size of the array, but the user should not need to explicitly provide it.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Consider making your "user override" modify the existing object instead of defining the object a second time.

Comment: Interesting idea, however the "existing object" at hand is an array and I'd like to avoid heap allocating a vector to push into it because of the small SRAM on arduino.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking how a data structure can vary in length without using heap memory?  There are many approaches.  Look into how "C style strings" work.  You could also solve this with `#ifdef`, but it's unclear why you think that's not sufficiently "easy".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's time to reach for a good old-fashioned pointer.  Something like:

```
class Combo {
   ...
};

extern const Combo *combos;
extern const int combos_count;
```

And then:

```
#include "combo.h"

const Combo combo1, combo2, combo3;
const Combo my_combos [] = { combo1, combo2, combo3 };
const Combo *combos = my_combos;
const int combo_count = sizeof (my_combos) / sizeof (my_combos [0]);
```

I dropped the macro (don't like it / don't need it) and the rather pointless use of `uint8_t`.  You should also provide some kind of access function to check whether `combos` is `nullptr` and whether `combos_count` is out of bounds/